# GetComponent With Reflection

Tags: c#

I am trying get a Form's BindingSource using Reflection. The following code is what I've tried so far although it has an error:

```
public class MyClass :Form
{
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
}

public static class Class2
{
    public static BindingSource GetBindingSource(string FieldNameP, Form FormP)
    {
        BindingSource Bs = null;

        var info=FormP.GetType().GetField(FieldNameP);
        if(info != null)
        {
            Bs = (BindingSource)info.GetValue(null)
        }

        return Bs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your call to get field, you need to use the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ek9c21e.aspx) that accepts [binding flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx). You may need to trial and error it a bit but I think your need:

```
BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance
```

`.GetValue` takes the instance of the object you want to invoke the field on.

```
.GetValue(myform);
```

A better approach may be to create an interface:

```
public interface IBindable
{
    BindingSource Source { get; }
}
```

Apply it to the form:

```
public class MyClass : Form, IBindable
{
    private BindingSource _Source = new BindingSource();
    public BindingSource Source { get { return _Source; } }
}
```

Use the interface:

```
BindingSource formSource = MyForm.Source;
```

Comment: I can get BindingSource Fieldinfo but 
I can not create a bindingsource with Info.GetValue

It error message like
is not a field on the target object which is of type 'system.runtimetype'

Comment: @user1624185 Pass your instance of the form to .GetValue(...) instead of null. You are asking it to get field "bs" on "null".

Comment: public static void SqlQuery(string QueryP,Form FormP)
        {
                   
var info = FormP.GetType().GetField("Bs",BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public);

if (info != null)
{
BindingSource Bs=null;
Bs=(BindingSource)info.GetValue(FormP.GetType());
}
 
           }


Error like
Field bs on type FormXXXX is not a field on the target
object which is of type 'system.runtimetype'

Comment: public static void SqlQuery(string QueryP,Form FormP) { var info = FormP.GetType().GetField("Bs",BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.Public); if (info != null) { BindingSource Bs=null; Bs=(BindingSource)info.GetValue(FormP.GetType()); } } Error like Field bs on type FormXXXX is not a field on the target object which is of type 'system.runtimetype'

Comment: @user1624185 You need to pass the INSTANCE of the form to `.GetValue(...);`. So assuming `Form FormP` is actually of type `MyClass` you would call `.GetValue(FormP);`.